# How to work with strings and pointers in C?

Tags: c

1. Why is it `p+=*string[2]-*string[1]` instead of `p+=string[2]-string[1]` (without asterisks)?
2. `res[0]=*p;` its value is `'c'` why? Why `p` moves on the word letters while `*string[1]` moves among the words and not letters?

   #####I have edited the code.........did "char* p=*string;" can be replaced by "char* p=*string[0];"?

The code's output is

> c

```
 int main (void)
 {
   char* strings[]={"abcdb","bbb","dddd"};
   char*p=*strings;
   char res[2];
   p+=*string[2]-*string[1];
   res[0]=*p;
   p+=3;
   res[1]=*p;
   printf("%s\n",res);
   return 0;   
 }
```

Comment: Where is `string` defined? Is that a typo error of `strings`? Note that the code should be printing "cb" not "c" but you have Undefined Behaviour due to `res` being an unterminated string.

Comment: @lucky The program has undefined behaviour and the reason is not that that was pointed by Weather Vane . The reason is that you are trying to dereference the pointer beyond the string literal "abc" That is this statement res[1]=*p; is already invalid.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow did you mean *in addition* to what I wrote, or that my comment about an unterminated string was wrong?

Comment: @Weather Vane I mean that the undefined behaviour took place already before the printf statement.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow that's true, but Undefined Behaviour does not mean a program fails. If it survived the first (for me it did) then it can fail on the second (it did). UB can be entirely as was expected, but is not defined to be so by the C standard.

Answer (score 2):

The program has undefined behaviour.

We will not take into account that there is a typo and instead of identifier `strings` there is sometimes used identifier `string`. Let's assume that everywhere in the code snippet there is used identifier `strings`.

In this statement

```
char*p=*strings;
```

the first element of the array is assigned to the pointer. The first element of the array is pointer to the first character of string literal `"abc"`. So p points to character `'a'` of the string literal.

In this statement

```
p += *strings[2] - *strings[1];
```

`strings[2]` is the third element of the array having type `char *` and its value is the address of the first character of string literal `"dddd"`. Dereferencing this pointer `*strings[2]` you will get the first character of this string literal that is `'d'`

`strings[1]` is the second element of the array having type `char *` and its value is the address of the first character of string literal `"bbb"`. Dereferencing this pointer `*strings[1]` you will get the first character of this string literal that is `'b'

The difference between internal codes of characters `'d'` and `'b' (for example in ASCII the code of character`'b'`is 98 while the code of`'d'` is 100) is equal to 2.

So this statement

```
p += *strings[2]-*strings[1];
```

increases the pointer by 2. At first it pointed to character `'a'` of the first string literal `"abc"` and after increasing by 2 it points now to character `'c'` of the same string literal `"abc"`.

Thus in this statement

```
res[0] = *p;
```

character `'c'` is assigned to `res[0]`.

After this statement

```
p+=3;
```

the value of `p` becomes invalid because it now points beyond the string literal "abc" and it is not necessary that the compiler placed string literal `"bbb"` exactly after string literal `"abc"`.

So dereferencing this pointer in the next statement

```
res[1]=*p;
```

results in undefined behaviour.

According to the C Standard

> If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it
>   shall not be used as the operand of a unary * operator that is
>   evaluated

It simply occured such a way that the compiler placed the string literals one after another in the memory. Though this is not guaranteed by the Standard.

So if after statement

```
res[1]=*p;
```

res[1] does not contain character `'\0'` then the next statement

```
printf("%s\n",res);
```

also has undefined behaviour.

Comment: If he had declared strings as char strings[][5]={"abc","bbb","dddd"}; .Will it be neccessary that "bbb" is stored just after "abc" ?

Comment: @Sourav Kanta  Arrays are contiguous extents of memory. In this case it is guaranteed that "bbb" is stored exactly after "abc". and between them there are two zero characters.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is there is nothing like `string` defined in your program, so your statement should be `p+=*strings[2]-*strings[1]`

Answer to both of your question is **Dereferencing  a pointer**. You need to understand, how pointers work on Strings. Please check [this link](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/string/intro/).